# How to use local machine image in react js using PROPS

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I want to render my local machine image using props. am a beginner so please help me with the simplest method. Thanks in advance.

I exporting my card.js and rendering in App.js

App.js code below

> import React from "react";
> import Card from "./card";
> import logo from "./img/imge.jpg";
>
> ```
>     const App = () => {
>         return(
>             <>
>             <Card img= {require('./img/imge.jpg')}/>
>             </>
>         )
>     }
>     
>     export default App;
> ```

Card.js code below

> import React from "react";
>
> ```
> const Card = ({img}) => (
>     <>
>     <p>my name is {img}</p>
>     </>
> )
> export default Card;
> ```

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: On image, there is your name?

Comment: what is aim on your project?

Comment: hello, Do you read my answer?

Comment: hello, @Ranjan_bastia where is  your image file? Can you tell me your file structure?

Answer (score 1):

App.js

```js
import MyImage from "./path/to/image.jpg"
import React from "react";
import Card from "./card"; 
import logo from "./img/imge.jpg";

const App = () => <Card img= {logo}/>;

export default App;
```

Card.js

```js
const Card = ({img}) => <p>my name is <img src="{img}"/></p>;

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0):

> <Card img= {require('./img/imge.jpg')}/>

I think main problem is folder structure. Please check my codesandbox.

**App.js**

```
            <>
               <Card img= {require('./img/image.png')}/>
            </>
```

**card.js**

```
    <p>my name is <img src={img} alt="myname" width="300px"/></p>
```

**CodeSandbox URL**

> https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-kare-iw5jt?file=/src/App.js:126-166

Comment: I can see alt only not the image.